# Cannot extract data from a json column in a table

Tags: sql, json, database, postgresql, extract

I have a table name `orders` and there is a column name `adressJson` which contains Json data comma seperated, I want an pgsql query to extract data from it from all rows and make a new table of it in tableau

```json
{
  "full_name": "xxx",
  "contact_number": "xxxx",
  "title": "xxxx",
  "zone_number": "0",
  "street_number": "1",
  "building_number": "27",
  "business_address": "xxx",
  "latitude": 123,
  "longitude": 123,
  "country": "xxx",
  "apartment_number": "27"
}
```

I have tried

```sql
SELECT "orders"."id", "orders"."order_id", "addressJson"."full_name"
FROM "public"."orders" "orders"
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
SELECT (addressJson->>'status') AS status, (addressJson->>'full_name') AS full_name
FROM jsonb_array_elements(("orders.addressJson")) AS addressJson
) AS addressJson
```

but its not working it shows

```
ERROR:  column "orders.addressJson" does not exist
LINE 5: FROM jsonb_array_elements(("orders.addressJson")) AS address...
                                   ^ 

SQL state: 42703
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the lateral join in this case. Just extract the value of attribute `full_name` from the JSON column.

```sql
SELECT id, order_id, 
       "addressJson"::json ->> 'full_name' as full_name
FROM public.orders;
```

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fs5bssavvAv7knadpS9QHv/2)

Comment: Thanks, but im still getting this error 

`ERROR:  operator does not exist: text ->> unknown
LINE 2:        "addressJson" ->> 'full_name' as full_name
                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. `

Comment: @Saamia This means that column `adressJson` is not of type JSON. Pls. add sample table data to the question

Comment: @Saamia Also post the actual table definition (ddl) for the `orders`` table.

Comment: ![It shows that its 'text', but the data its containing is json, should I use CAST func?](https://imgur.com/a/neafbo1)

Comment: @Saamia Yes, try to replace `"addressJson"` with `"addressJson"::json` as in the modified answer.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm thanks, I got it, what the problem was, some of the rows in the addressJson column were invalid, thats why the query was not working.